# Rails 4.2, scss, html, Bootstrap. Apply css conditionally to hide part of the DOM.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I have a site wide side bar, on the left. It's part of a Bootstrap `nav`. The side bar is collapsed on `sm` screens and below but, toggable via a button. This is working fine.

Simply put; I'd like to collapse/hide the sidebar when it is empty too, without it affecting the existing behavior described above.

I've tried to hide JQuery's `hide()` and `show()`, however this breaks the existing functionality.

I've also described the javascript snippet below, without success.

**.../navigation_partial.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <%# layout content omitted  %>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div>
        <%= link_to something %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%# collapsed for mobile  %>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <%# bunch of links%>
        <li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</head>

<%# Side bar component  %>
<div class="row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= yield :sidebar  %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="main">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%# button to toggle sidebar %>
      <p class="visible-xs">
        <button type="button" id="sidebar-toggle-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="sidebar">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </button>
      </p>
      <body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
        <%# Page content  %>
        <div id="primary-content">
          <%= yield  %>
        </div>
      </body>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.../sidebar.scss**

```
//Sidebar which collapses on small devices, being toggable by button
#sidebar {
  width           : inherit;
  min-width       : 160px;
  max-width       : 160px;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  float           : left;
  height          :100%;
  position        :relative;
  overflow-y      :auto;
  overflow-x      :hidden;
}

body,html,.row-offcanvas {
  height: 100%;
}

//Trigger collapse on small devices
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position          : relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition   : all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition        : all 0.25s ease-out;
    width             :calc(100% + 160px);
  }
  .row-offcanvas-left {
    left: -160px;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top     : 0;
  }
}

//Primary page content sits within this div
#main {
  height  :100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

The code snippets above work fine for toggling the sidebar on `xs` screens (collapsed by default).

Below is my attempt at get the desired behavior, collapsing the sidebar on any screen if it's empty, using javascript (and JQuery).

**.../sidebar.js**

```
function hideSidebarIfEmpty() {
    if ($("#sidebar div.col-xs-12").children().length <= 0) {
      $(".row-offcanvas").css("position","relative");
      $(".row-offcanvas").css("-webkit-transition","all 0.25s ease-out");
      $(".row-offcanvas").css("-moz-transition","all 0.25s ease-out");
      $(".row-offcanvas").css("transistion","all 0.25s ease-out");
      $(".row-offcanvas").css("width","calc(100% + 160px)");
      $(".row-offcanvas-left").css("left","-160px");
      $(".row-offcanvas-left.active").css("left","0");
      $(".sidebar-offcanvas").css("position","absolute");
      $(".sidebar-offcanvas").css("top","0");
    } else {
      // lots of '.css("property","");' calls
    };
  };
```

Comment: What happens with your solution ? do you want it to still be "toggleable" even if without any elements inside? When are the elements for the nav defined (at render time or by user interaction on client side)?

Comment: My attempted solution is crap.

Behavior i'd like to see is:

- when content within side bar, toggable on small screens always present on > small (this is the current behaviour site wide)
- when no content within side bar, hide the side bar on all screens.

Comment: I'm not saying it's good, I'm asking what happens. And when are the elements for the nav defined, only at render time? Why doesn't jquery hide() work for you? What do you mean, breaks the existing functionality? You want to hide it but want it to still be functional- what does this mean? You can prevent it from rendering in the first place. You can change its opacity to 0, send it back with a negative z-index, define 0 width/height, remove it from the dom, apply a specific class that hides it, so it kinda depends on what you want, what isn't working and how you want it to work

Comment: Thanks for your comments Miceal. In parsing your questions, I've settled on a solution. To not render the sidebar to begin with.

In future questions, I will be more explicit in my prose.